# docker cli application with a dockerized web ui to control

Tags: rest, docker, docker-compose

New to docker here, was wondering if anyone had any suggestions for having a dockerized CLI application and then having a separate docker container used to control it (web REST API).

CLI Application
REST API -> makes calls to CLI application via bash

I tried linking, but this only provides network connectivity, what I need is access to the environment of the other container, while also maintaining two separate containers (incase we need to upgrade the REST container more frequently than the application).

Docker saying is one process one container, but if that CLI isn't accessible it makes it hard to make web calls against it.

Anyone dealt with this or have any suggestions?

Comment: Why does the REST client need access to the environment of the web service container?  That seems like not a very useful client (ie., how would one ever run it remotely?)

Comment: REST service needs access to an underlieing application via command line. ie. Shelling out a command to the container that has the application running. so restapi I call /create and it shells out a command <program> create <parameter> etc and returns result.  This works if both processes are in the same container, but I don't think this is a good design.

Answer (score 0):

This might sound advertisement, but check out [Athena](https://athena-oss.github.io/) - An automation platform with a plugin architecture that allows you to easily create and share services (using bash and docker) and some of the plugins available.

I am mentioning this because we have used it for some scenarios like the one you are mentioning.

P.S.: if the moderators feel like i am going against the rules please remove my comment.

Comment: It's not against the rules to provide a link to external resources, but you should tell something about "how to use" so that OP can see how the tool fits their needs